# Entity framework: adding new objects results in duplicates

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I'm developing a 3-tier WinForms application. But when I try to add a new object to the database, some objects get duplicated.

Classes:

```
class Customer 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<CustomerAccount> CustomerAccount { get; set; }
}

class CustomerAccount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}

class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AccountName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code I use to add the Customer object to the database:

```
 DataContext.CustomerSet.Add(customer);
 DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

The accounts that are added to the customer are existing accounts. And these are the rows that are duplicated in the database. So for example:

```
Customer c;
c.CustomerName = "Kevin";

c.CustomerAccount.Add(new CustomerAccount() {
    AccountId = existingAccountId,
    Account = existingAccount
}

AddCustomer(c);
```

In this example, existingAccount gets duplicated.

I know it's something with the DataContext.Attach() method. But that doesn't work when there is more than one CustomerAccount relation added. (An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.)

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Only set `existingAccountId`.

Comment: How do I get the properties of the Account then? I use the Customer/Account properties for navigation purposes.

Comment: Oh, you can hang on to the `Account` property, but you don't have to set both. When you fetch Customer from the database you can access their `CustomerAccount.Account` and the `Account` data will be available.

Comment: Thx, this fixes the problem when attaching a detached entity. The only problem I now have is: because everything is detached, the navigation property is not working. Anyway to make that work? It only works when fetching existing record.

Comment: In that case you should attach the `Account` to the context the `Customer` is attached to and set `CustomerAccount.Account` after all. (In which case you don't have to set `AccountId`).

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a new instance of CustomerAccount. you must reload it from your database and work with the object from the Context.

```
    Customer c;
    c.CustomerName = "Kevin";

    var customerAccount = DataContext.CustomerAccount.First( c => c.AccountId == existingAccountId)


    c.CustomerAccount = customerAccount;
    DataContext.Customer.Add(c);
    DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The CustomerAccount object is a relation. So fetching an existing one, makes no sense. Only the Account objects exist in the database. The relation between Customer and Account has yet to be defined by adding it.